# Double pole 25 amp breaker to single pole 20 amp breaker

Tags: electrical

I have a single circuit that is on a double pole 25 amp breaker at 240v. This appears as if it supplied power to an old defunct well pump. I have had this breaker off for some months so I'm fairly positive that is all that it used to power. I want to change this to a single 120v 20 amp breaker to supply a single 15 amp outlet.

Am I correct in my plan of going to buy the same brand 20 amp breaker and a breaker space cover and literally just swapping the single in for the double? Anything missing?

Got some pictures of the panel and the offending breaker that I want to switch out ....

https://photos.app.goo.gl/NE1twrbKEFbk6Gvc6

Comment: Why not do a 20 amp outlet? Assuming the wire is 10 AWG you should have no issue using the screw on the side of the outlet. Don't you dare try to use the backstabs!!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you, please see my comment below

Comment: I see. Then it's important for your breaker to be 15 amp since the extension cord is only rated for 15 amps.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus can you explain the reasoning? I'm not trying to be combative, just still learning.      My current thought pattern is still doing a 20 amp with a 20amp outlet would be able to supply the cord just fine and the problem would come if I were to try to draw more than 15 amp through the cord....

Comment: That's exactly the problem. If you plug in a multi-outlet strip in the shed and overload it with 20A for a while (e.g., 12A heater plus some tools), the breaker will *not* trip because it is OK with 20A. And the wiring inside the wall will be fine. But the extension cord is likely to have a meltdown.

Comment: In a nutshell, it sounds like your extension cord is a planned "permanary" extension of your electrical system so you need to size the breaker for the lowest common denominator; 15 amp extension cord. The dangers of electricity are all about amperage pulled over a given distance for a given amount of time. The 15 amp cord is fine if you NEVER pull more than 15 amps or 80% of 15 for 24/7. Your thought process is based on human trust, the 15 amp breaker is based on safety.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  ahhhh ok, that makes complete sense. Thank you.  Really I'm trying to run a miter saw (15 amp) along with 1 led light, shop vac and possibly a fan at the same time. Right now I have a 15 amp outlet going through a 15 amp power inlet and I know that won't be enough. Soo, I'm thinking I could have a double cord setup with two inlets with one decorated to only the miter saw. I've been trying to think through this with what I have available. I suppose I could get a 20 amp inlet and a 20 amp extension cord to do with a 20 amp outlet and 20 amp breaker.....

Comment: @MonkeyZeus very good point! Don't trust the human lol. Oh and I will be plugging and unplugging the extension cord and not leaving it plugged in 24/7

Comment: What you *really* want is 2 circuits. That way you can have the lights & vac on one and the saw (or other tools) on the other. Which can be done with either 2 separate runs or what is called a **MWBC** - using two hots + neutral to get two x 15A or two x 20A (depending on the breaker). The catch is that using extension cord/inlet/etc. (in this case, it would be 2 extension cords, etc.) is OK temporarily but not as a permanent installation - and what you describe is, in reality, a permanent installation.

Comment: Like I said, "The dangers of electricity are all about amperage pulled over a given distance for a given amount of time." You'd probably be fine running the shop vac and miter saw at the same time for brief (15 second periods); I assume you're using the vacuum for dust collection. But if there is nothing stopping you from exceeding the rating of the cord then you have a fire hazard. The right answer is to use a 20 amp extension cord; not two fifteens because nothing is stopping you from abusing the undersized extension cord.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact clarifying, I will be plugging and unplugging the extension cord as i have no problem doing that. We hire a lawn mowing company and the last thing I want is to leave this cord strewn across the lawn when I'm not around lol

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think you've settled it in my mind. I was planning to do two runs with 2 15 amp extension cords but I'm leaning toward getting another power inlet rated at 20 amp, 20 amp ext cord, 20 amp outlet, with 20 p breaker and be able to run everything off of one cord....

Comment: @onlettinggo I'm glad I could help you avoid a fire hazard =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you! How would you handle the 20 amps once inside she's? I'm assuming just plugging in a regular ole power strip would bring up the same fire hazard issue because the power strip won't be rated at 20

Comment: Look into heavy duty cords like this one https://www.amazon.com/Yellow-Jacket-2882-Available-Extension/dp/B000BQU576/ref=asc_df_B000BQU576/

Comment: See NEC Table 400.5(A)(1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcCV2.png , it shows cord amperage. #14  cords are good for 18A, a #12 is good for 21A. So you could ask why they call a #14 a 15A cord? A very least is would require 20A plug cord end https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0166/0070/products/5-20p_large.jpg?v=1488125262 then you couldn't plug it into a standard 15A receptacle. Also notice( nearly) all 20A receptacles accept 15A cords. This is considered reasonably safe or the NEC wouldn't allow it. Go with Ed Beal's answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That is a good cord, but really much more of a 1-to-3 expander, since it is only 2 feet long. I'd typically see that as "long extension cord into the yard, add this to allow multiple devices at the same time". Presumably the shed is more than 2' away from the house.

Comment: @manasseh Well if this is a shopping question then check out https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B01FX6JRWC/

Comment: Thank y'all for the input into this. The more I think about it the more I just want to replace the double 25 with a single 15 GFCI breaker to duplex 15 outlet and just run 2 extension cords to the shed and call it a day. That way I'll have 2 circuits, dedicate one to tool use and the other to accessory use. Won't be a big deal plugging and unplugging 2 cords. I already have 95% of the things I need and won't have to spend additional $. It will hold me over until I can pony up the thousands of dollars to run proper electric

Answer (score 1):

Basically correct. But a few things to consider:

- Breaker Type

Most *new* circuits require AFCI and/or GFCI. AFCI is generally best handled at the breaker. GFCI can be at the breaker or at the receptacle. Locations needing AFCI or GFCI vary depending on the version of the NEC. Generally speaking, kitchen, bathroom, garage, unfinished basement, laundry room and outdoor receptacles all need GFCI and most others need AFCI.

Based on additional details, this is feeding a shed, so GFCI is a definite requirement, and weather resistant and an in-use cover are also requirements. Note that even with WR receptacles, GFCI is more vulnerable when outside, so that is a point in favor of using a GFCI breaker, despite the additional cost.

- Breaker Size

A 15A breaker can be used with 14 AWG or 12 AWG wire, or larger. A 15A breaker can connect to any number of 15A receptacles - 1 or more.

A 20A breaker can be used with 12 AWG wire or larger. A 20A breaker can connect to any number of 20A receptacles - 1 or more. Or it can connect to *at least 2* 15A receptacles. A standard duplex receptacle counts as "2".

So you can't connect a 20A circuit breaker to only *one* 15A receptacle. Either use a 20A receptacle or a duplex 15A receptacle. Or use a 15A breaker and a single 15A receptacle. While most of the time more receptacles is better, there are situations where connecting just 1 receptacle to a circuit is the right thing to do, as long as it matches the breaker.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This outlet will be located inside a storage cubby and go via a 15 amp rated extension cord to a power inlet through the wall of a shed. It's way to expensive for me to run proper power to the shed so this will have to do for now.                      About the other users comment on my original question, I think I will switch to a 20amp outlet even though it won't make a difference I think...

Comment: The way you have worded the 15 amp receptacle on a 20 amp circuit is hard to read. Just saying since a GFCI Is required I just use that as I haven’t seen a single GFCI receptacle,  a dead face sure but really?

Comment: @EdBeal What I'm *trying* to say is that based on the original language "single 120v 20 amp breaker to supply a single 15 amp outlet" there would be a code violation. The *practical* situation is: Need GFCI. GFCI cheapest at the receptacle. GFCI is pretty much always duplex receptacle. Therefore unlikely to actually *install* a single 15A. But if OP stuck to the original plan *exactly* (and presumably satisfied GFCI requirement at the breaker) then there would be a problem.

Comment: I did understand but it was hard to read and I know the code, just mentioning it to help future answers.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact right, what I should have said is 20 amp breaker and a duplex 15 amp outlet. Language and the way people will interpret said language is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Wow some crazy mis information on this!!!
Yes you can downsize to a single 20 amp circuit breaker.
Outside you will need a GFCI protected receptacle.
In a cubby or a dry location I would still suggest a weather resistant 15 or 20 amp GFCI receptacle so it can be reset locally.
You can use a duplex 15 amp receptacle on a 20 amp circuit it is allowed by code.
The standard extension cord is legal most don’t realize cordage actually has higher ampacitys than promoter wiring of the same gauge.
The other thing is have you ever seen a 20 amp 120v extension cord? I am an electrician and other than ones I have made I don’t remember ever seeing one much less a 20 amp plug in device. (Ok I have seen a few but extremely rare).
So change to a 20 amp breaker move the white to the neutral buss in the main panel ground and neutral are the same/ can be mixed.

Use a 15 or 20 amp wr rated GFCI receptacle

And you are good to go, to comment on the backstab raised above you could not use the back stab on a 15a receptacle if you wanted to because these are sized for 14 awg wire and 12 won’t fit so 10 really won’t fit. The screw lugs are the only way to go.

Comment: Yes 20A cords are rare. This rare UL approved cord  https://amzn.to/3BfgISI (male 20A plug, female 15/20A receptacle) in a way confirms it is acceptable to plug a 15A device into a 20A circuit.